# How to invoke email-ext plugin from Jenkins declarative script?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I am writing a simple Jenkins declarative script to run 'make' and send an email with the result (success/failure).

I can send a simple email using:

```
post {
    success {
        mail to:"myname@me.com", subject:"${currentBuild.fullDisplayName} - Failed!", body: "Success!"
    }
    failure {
        mail to:"myname@me.com", subject:"${currentBuild.fullDisplayName} - Failed!", body: "Failure!"
    }
}
```

The resulting email is rather simplistic.

How can I call the email-ext plugin from the script to send an old-style post-build email?  (I guess this should use email-ext's groovy-text.template).

I would like to be able to access lists like CulpritsRecipientProvider and to include the tail of the console log.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use it in this way:

```
emailext (
    subject: "STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
    body: """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
        <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>""",
    recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']]
)
```

For more information you can check:

- [Sending Notifications in Pipeline](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/sending-notifications-pipeline)
- [Email Extension Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/)

Comment: Yes, anything you could do in Groovy Script pipelines you can do it in Declarative Syntax, in case you need some script, use "script" step https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-model-definition/#script-run-arbitrary-pipeline-script

Comment: Thanks again, so now I have:     post {
        success {
            script: emailext (subject: "STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]'",
                              body: """<p>STARTED: Job '${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]':</p>
                              <p>Check console output at &QUOT;<a href='${env.BUILD_URL}'>${env.JOB_NAME} [${env.BUILD_NUMBER}]</a>&QUOT;</p>""",
                              recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider']])
        }
    }

Comment: I get error: "An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored. " How do I set the recipients?

Comment: Configure some mails: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/attachment/32671/Global%20configuration.png

Comment: Daniel, thanks for your help. My problem is that my intended list of recipients varies from project to project, so I can't specify them in the global configuration. I want to specify them in the script. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: In this case it might be easier to use token macros. You can find a list of them here: https://gist.github.com/arjabbar/c6f27c64fd18153680f3b52102688c13

Comment: How to load style through jenkins