# Jenkins output String After build

Tags: jenkins

Recently I've got a Jenkins Job which run a couple of tests and generate a string report.

I want to send it to informers but I cannot find the way to achieve the goal.

Let me show you what I want to do.

[image]

while executing this command, it'll do some calculation and generate a string output.

And I want to use this string here, (get the string and use it as ${REPORT} in content box)
[image]

Is there any way to do that?

Appreciate!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You got a Jenkins Job that generate the string report, but then you are asking again whether you can generate the string report on Jenkins?

Comment: Please be more specific, exactly what you want. Do you want an e-mail report of your job or are you looking for a specific output or ...

Comment: @JGK Sorry for the inconvenience, I've update the description.

Comment: @VictorWong Sorry for the inconvenience, I've update the description.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing this with a declarative pipeline. Assign the command output to $report then do whatever you want with it further.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ('Generate report') {
            steps {
                script {
                    report = bat(script: "cd analysis && npm run jenkins-update && npm run jenkins-report", returnStatus: true)
                    // Do whatever you want with $report such as attaching it in an email
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext%2Bplugin). A good start are the [recipes](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+Recipes) on the plugin website.

See also this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982256/how-to-invoke-email-ext-plugin-from-jenkins-declarative-script).